# R - what is the best way to plot multiple functions $y=cx$ where c is a parameter

Tags: r

I want to plot the function y=cx  depending on c. It is going to be number of lines going through the point (0,0).

What is the best way to do it?

I mean something like this:
[image]

Using `abline` function seems to be the way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint, define a function like `f <- function(x,a,b,i) x^a * b + i` then try `curve(f(x,a=2,b=3,i=1), from=1, to=10)` - you can adjust the `a/b/i` values as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this should work. Not sure if it's the best way though

```
plot(x = 0,y = 0,xlab = "X",ylab = "Y", xlim = c(-10,10), ylim = c(-10,10))

c <- c(1:10) #Store the different values of your constant in this vector

for(i in 1:10){
   abline(coef = c(0,c[i]))
}
```

If you want different limits on your X and Y axis change the values of `xlim` and `ylim`.

Comment: how about if it was a different function lets say y=x+c?

Comment: @Michal: Stop changing the question! Edit your question to ask the question your _really_ want answered. It _should_ have some data.

Comment: @Michal: What @42- said is correct. Ask all parts of your question at one time. Anyway, the `coef` argument for `abline` takes a two element vector as a value. The first is the intercept and the second the slope. So you'd just have to do `abline(coef = c(c[i],0))` where c holds the values of your intercept.